# Alter column type from int or bigint to timestamp

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I currently have a bigint with timestamps in millis, instead i want to change to the standard "timestamp" column type.

Using:

```
ALTER TABLE groupgps ALTER COLUMN date_stamp TYPE timestamp
```

I get:

```
column "date_stamp" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
```

Using:

```
ALTER TABLE groupgps ALTER COLUMN date_stamp TYPE timestamp with time zone USING date_stamp::timestamp with time zone
```

I get:

```
cannot cast type bigint to timestamp with time zone
```

Really at a loss here beyond re-making the table from scratch, but i believe i'd need to recreate all the indexes and anything that referenced the table before i deleted it.

Comment: [`to_timestamp()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)?

Comment: Wait just to be sure, do you mean milliseconds or seconds? You wrote `millis`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `ALTER ... USING` statement.

Test data, from your sample.

```
CREATE TABLE groupgps AS
SELECT date_stamp::bigint
FROM generate_series(1,100) AS date_stamp;
```

### With `to_timestamp()`

It seems you can also use the `to_timestamp` function. [The docs pointing to `to_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) claim that this,

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 982384720.12 * INTERVAL '1 second';

The to_timestamp function encapsulates the above conversion.
```

So we can use that in our `ALTER TABLE ... USING` too,

```
ALTER TABLE groupgps
    ALTER COLUMN date_stamp SET DATA TYPE timestamp with time zone
    USING to_timestamp(date_stamp);
```

### Without using `to_timestamp()`

Then we adapt the example from [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).

```
ALTER TABLE groupgps
    ALTER COLUMN date_stamp SET DATA TYPE timestamp with time zone
    USING
        timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + date_stamp * interval '1 second';
```

Comment: Yep, this is what it took. I actually managed to figure it out shortly after posting, - as is always the way - I specifically used the (USING to_timestamp()) which you mentioned so i'll mark this as the answer anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a direct cast from `bigint` to `timestamp` in Postgres.  But you can create a new `timestamp` column and populate it with your `bigint` column, going through text.

```
ALTER TABLE groupgps ADD COLUMN time_stamp timestamp with time zone;
UPDATE groupgps
SET time_stamp = '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT'::timestamp +
                 ((date_stamp)::text)::interval;
```

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200207251134.16658.dev@archonet.com